# User input - Javascript Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, input, console

I'm new to js programming and to stackoverflow, I have a school homework in which i have to make a parser for vcards (the parser works fine, I can extract all the information I need) but in this parser I have to check if the contact(s) have more then two phone numbers and if they do they must choose at most 2 phone numbers. for this I made this function :

```
function checkPhone() {
//compter le nombre de numéro par contact j
for (i = 1; i < nbrContact; i++) {
    var count = 0;


    //count phone numbers for one contact
    for (u = 0; u < nbrPhones; u++) {
        if (phoneOf(i)[u] != undefined) {
            count++;
        }
    }


    //if a contact has more then 2 phone numbers
    if (count > 2) {
        var question1 = "There are " + count + " phone numbers for the contact " + "\"" + fullName[i] + "\"" + ", Please choose the two you want to keep";
        console.log(question1);

        //print the phone numbers and their type for each contact 
        for (u = 0; u < count; u++) {
            console.log(u  + "      " + phoneOf(i)[u] + " : " + phoneTypeOf(i)[u]);
        }
    }
}
```

}

PS : the phoneOf() and phoneTypeOf() returns arrays with the phone numbers and their types for each contact

basically this function gives me this for a sample vcard with multiple contacts and two of them have more than 2 phones numbers:  (I need 10 reputation to post images please check this link [here](http://www.upload-image.fr/images/2014/12/01/Sans_titre.png))

and the user must input a number in this case the variable "u", and i can't figure it out.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how the user can input the value of "u"? But, u is a variable you are using as a counter.

Comment: I just want to save the input to u,  if you check the image it will probably give you an idea.
(english is my third language sorry if i'm not clear)

Comment: Seems like if you want to do a console application just like c or other lenguages, readline unstable module could do the trick for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var readline = require('readline'); //add this ...
var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function checkPhone() {
    //compter le nombre de numéro par contact j
    for (i = 1; i < nbrContact; i++) {
        var count = 0;


        //count phone numbers for one contact
        for (u = 0; u < nbrPhones; u++) {
            if (phoneOf(i)[u] != undefined) {
                count++;
            }
        }


        //if a contact has more then 2 phone numbers
        if (count > 2) {
            var question1 = "There are " + count + " phone numbers for the contact " + "\"" + fullName[i] + "\"" + ", Please choose the two you want to keep";
            console.log(question1);

            //print the phone numbers and their type for each contact 
            for (u = 0; u < count; u++) {
              console.log(u)  + "      " + phoneOf(i)[u] + " : " + phoneTypeOf(i)[u]);
            }
            rl.question('wich numbers would you like to keep?:', function(numbers){
                //parse the numbers maybe with an input 0,1 to keep number 0 and 1...
                rl.close(); //is important to close it
            })

        }
    }
}
```

Take in count that readline is unstable and is open to changes..

Here is the [documentation of readline](http://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks like the  right way to do it i just have to save the 'u' variables in an array and compare them to the input